# Previous URL with subdomain

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have subdomain `account.asu.dev`.The controller has the code:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

This construct directs the user to the login page. The problem is that _previous takes `auth.asu.dev` value, but should `account.asu.dev`. For this reason, the user is taken to the main page, but had to return to the subdomain. How to fix it?

Laravel 5.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are manually loging in users, you could do at the end of the login

```
return redirect()->intended('home');
```

This will redirect them where they were going or simply to the home page. Or simply replace `home` with whatever page you want them to go after the login works.

Comment: Thank you so much.